# Need help with some functions and variables

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function createXMLHTTP() {
           xmlhttp = =new XMLHttpRequest();
           return xmlhttp;
}
```

I'm trying to create 3 instances of this, but it all has the same variable name which is xmlhttp. How can I dynamically create different variable names? I'm not sure if that's the right way to ask the question.

I want to create like xmlhttp1, xmlhttp2, xmlhttp3, so then I can reference each one.

Comment: is there a reason why recursion or using a framework will not help?

Comment: Could you give me an example of both of those? I'm learning, so I really don't know the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a `function` call for an operation this simple.

```
x1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
x2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
x3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

But if you insist, then at least make it shorter.

```
function createXHR() {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to create many elements is to place them in an array:

```
var xmlhttprequests = [];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttprequests.push(xmlhttp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
function createXMLHTTP() {
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       return xmlhttp;
}

xmlhttp1 = createXMLHTTP();
xmlhttp2 = createXMLHTTP();
xmlhttp3 = createXMLHTTP();
```

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner